# Overriding Proper Java equals method

Tags: java, oop, overriding, equals

I am overriding the `equals()` method in a Java class and found a conundrum that I can't explain.

The standard `equals()` contract states this:

- It is reflexive: for any reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
- It is symmetric: for any reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
- It is transitive: for any reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
- It is consistent: for any reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified.
- For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

Therefore, the standard `equals()` method would be constructed like so:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (null == other) return false;
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof MyClassName)) return false;
    MyClassName that = (MyClassName) other;
    return this.myMemberVariable.equals(that.name);
}
```

Given class `Foo` and and class `Bar extends Foo`, both with a member variable `String baz`, the standard `equals()` method inside `Foo` looks like:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (null == other) return false;
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof Foo)) return false;
    Foo that = (Foo) other;
    return this.baz.equals(that.name);
}
```

Whereas the standard `equals()` method inside `Bar` looks like:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (null == other) return false;
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof Bar)) return false;
    Barthat = (Bar) other;
    return this.baz.equals(that.name);
}
```

If I had objects `Foo foo = new Foo("Test");` and `Bar bar = new Bar("Test");`, and I called `foo.equals(bar)`, this would return `true`. If I called `bar.equals(foo)`, by the symmetric clause of the `equals()` contract, this is broken because inside `equals()` of `Bar`, `(!(other instanceof Bar))` is `true`, making `Bar`'s `equal()` method return `false`, which isn't correct, it should be `true`, by logic (both objects `String baz` are equal to each other), and by the symmetry clause, where if `x.equals(y)`, `y.equals(x)` is inherently `true`.

I'm aware of the `getClass()` vs `instanceof` argument for overriding `equals()` and don't want another one of these arguments.

This brings me to my actual question. In such a case, how does one properly override the `equals()` method that follows the standard Java contract for equality?

Comment: The answer is in the question. Test if both objects have the same class.

Comment: There are simple articles about that
(http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html)(http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html)
(http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html)(http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html)
(http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17)(http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) But don't forget about writing proper hashCode() also.

Comment: @JBNizet The contract doesn't require that they be of the same class. In this instance, it looks like the OP intended for a `Foo` to equal a `Bar` if they have the same `baz`.

Comment: @John - Then why bother overriding `equals()` in the subclass?

Comment: @TedHopp Who said he should? The author himself said a `Foo` could equal a `Bar` if they share the same `baz`. `baz` is a property of the parent class, so why override `equals()` in the child class?

Comment: @John: I agree. If the OP really doesn't want to change the logic of equals(), he shouldn't override it. I assumed (perhaps naively) that he had a good reason to override it.

Comment: @John - I'm not saying that he should; I'm questioning why he would, given the semantics he's trying to achieve. OP is asking about "how does one properly override...". The entire question is moot unless `equals()` is being overridden.

Comment: @TedHopp The OP is asking how to PROPERLY override the equals method in a situation where it SHOULD NOT BE. The OP said that Foo's and Bar's can be equal if they share a common baz. If a Foo can equal a Baz, then Foo would, at best, override equals with an *identical* implementation. Why override an implementation with an identical implementation?

Comment: @John - That was the entire point of my comment: why bother trying to override equals properly when this is a situation where it (apparently) should not be overridden at all? Your original comment didn't really make the point.

Comment: @TedHopp Don't tag ME in a question that was directed at the OP! We've wasted time and effort agreeing with one another. The question clearly looks to be directed at me.

Comment: I disagree with the "close as duplicate" vote. Both questions address the same topic, but this version of the question has a far more detailed explanation of the problem, which adds significantly to our understanding.

Comment: @TarynEast Thank you. I also do not agree with the closure due to as the linked "duplicate" does not ask the same question as I do, and I have a specific reason for overriding the `equals()` method in the subclass `Bar`.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. To reopen it, you'll need to grab another four people to do likewise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question

- `Foo` can equal `Bar` if they have the same `baz`
- `Foo` can equal `Foo` if they have the same `baz`
- `Bar` can equal `Bar` if they have the same `baz`

This clearly shows that `Foo` and `Bar` will have the *exact same implementation* of `equals()`. Therefore, you should not override it at all.

If you were to try to ignore this and override it anyway, you would reach one obvious conclusion: you can't downcast a `Bar` to a `Foo`, but you *can* cast both arguments to `Bar`. As soon as you do that, you will realize that you could have simply used `.equals()` from `Bar`.